# Two separate lists with corresponding numbers. How to detect them remove them from the list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I'm looking to create a program which randomly generates coins on an 8x8 grid.  I've got two lists being created (one list for the X co-ordinate and list for the Y co-ordinate).  On these lists, the two co-ordinates cannot be the same.  It's difficult to explain, so here's what I mean by example:

```
[1, 7, 4, **6**, 9, 2, 3, **6**, 8, 0] (list for the x co-ordinate)
[9, 3, 3, **1**, 2, 8, 0, **1**, 6, 1] (list for the y co-ordinate)
```

So, two lists are created. However `(6,1)` appears twice.  I don't want this.  So, how would I allow for this in my code, to ensure that this is ignored and the numbers are regenerated into different co-ordinates?  The code I have is below, I don't really know how to implement such a system thing!

```
def treasurePro():
    global coinListX, coinListY
    coinListX = []
    coinListY = [] 
    for x in range(10): 
        num = randint(0,8) 
        coinListX.append(num) 
        print(coinListX)
    for x in range(10): 
        num = randint(0,8)
        if num == 0 and coinListX[x] == 0:
            treasurePro() #goes back to the beginning to restart.  
        else:
            coinListY.append(num) 
            print(coinListY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create two lists with coordinates, at least not initially. That only makes it harder to detect duplicates.

You could either create *tuples* with coordinates so you can detect duplicates, or even produce a range of integers that represent your coordinates in sequence, then sample from those. The latter is extremely efficient.

To create tuples, essentially you want to create 8 unique such tuples:

```
def treasurePro():
    coords = []
    while len(coords) < 8:
        coord = randint(0, 8), randint(0, 8)
        if coord not in coords:
            coords.append(coord)
    # now you have 8 unique pairs. split them out
    coinListX, coinListY = zip(*coords)
```

This isn't all that efficient, as the `coord not in coords` test has to scan the whole list which is growing with each new coordinate. For a large number of coordinates to pick, this can slow down significantly. You'd have to add an extra `seen = set()` object that you also add coordinates to and test again in the loop to remedy that. There is a better way however.

Your board is a 9x9 size, so you have 81 unique coordinates. If you used [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) on a [`range()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) (`xrange()` in Python 2), you could trivially create 8 unique values, then 'extract' a row and column number from those:

```
def treasurePro():
    coords = random.sample(range(9 * 9), 8)  # use xrange in Python 2
    coinListX = [c // 9 for c in coords]
    coinListY = [c % 9 for c in coords]
```

Here `random.sample()` guarantees that you get 8 unique coordinates.

This is also far more efficient than generating all possible tuples up-front; using `range()` in Python 3 makes the above use O(K) memory, where K is the number of values you need to generate, while creating all coordinates up front would take O(N^2) memory (where N is the size of a board side).

You may want to store a list of `(x, y)` coordinates still rather than use two separate lists. Create one with `coords = [(c // 9, c % 9) for c in coords]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your board is small enough that you can simply generate all possibilities, take a sample, and then transpose into the desired separate lists for X and Y.

```
possibilities = [(a,b) for a in range(10) for b in range(10)]
places = random.sample(possibilities, 10)
x,y = zip(*places)
```

Comment: This takes a lot more memory than needed of course. Using a `range()` is a lot more efficient, especially if the grid were to get a lot larger.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I suppose, but, like I said, it's currently small enough, and the resulting code is concise, clear, and fast enough, so I'm pretty okay with it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate random coordinates, but you also want to reject any
pair of coordinates that already appears in the list. (Incidentally,
instead of two separate lists of integers, I would suggest using one
list of ordered pairs, i.e., tuples of two integers.)

One way to reject duplicates would be to search the existing list for
the new set. This is O(n) and slower than it needs to be, though it
would certainly work in your use case where n can't exceed 64.

Another way would be to maintain a second data structure where you can
look up each of the 64 cells in O(1) time, such as an 8x8 array of
booleans. Indeed, you could use this one structure by itself; to get a
list of the coordinates used, just traverse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
cordX = [x for x in range(10)]
cordY = cordX[:] 
random.shuffle(cordX)
random.shuffle(cordY)
```